# What tags in HTML5 are acknowledged of being self-closing?

Tags: html

Here is the list that I got from [complete list of HTML5 self-closing tags](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html)

```
<area />
<base />
<br />
<col />
<command />
<embed />
<hr />
<img />
<input />
<keygen />
<link />
<meta />
<param />
<source />
<track />
<wbr />
```

I am wondering if it is complete, is there any else?

Comment: Did you try checking the W3C and/or WHATWG drafts?

Comment: Since the HTML 5 draft is still subject to change, there's no guarantee that any correct answer would remain correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like your list is complete according to [W3C list](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements) (but as Quentin point out, HTML5 draft is still subject to change)

**Besides**, according to various sources the following obsolete or non-standard tags are void:

```
basefont, bgsound, frame, isindex
```

Answer (score 18):

They are not self-closing elements. They are *void* elements.

Void elements must not have end-tags. In HTML5, `<br>` and `<br />` mean the same thing: they are both *start tags*! It just so happens that no end tag is required for these elements. There is no concept of a self-closing tag in HTML5.

So you might as well write these without the slash, although I personally find it more readable if the slash is present.

Answer (score 6):

The HTML Standard calls these [*void elements*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements). Here’s the current list:

- `area`
- `base`
- `br`
- `col`
- `embed`
- `hr`
- `img`
- `input`
- `keygen`
- `link`
- `menuitem`
- `meta`
- `param`
- `source`
- `track`
- `wbr`

However, based on the context within the HTML document, there may be more “self-closing” elements. To get the list of those, open [the HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) and search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) for `Acknowledge the token's self-closing flag`. For example, `math` and `svg` can be self-closing. `script` can be self-closing in an SVG context.