# Test if an element can contain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there a clean and robust way in which I can test (using pure javascript or also jQuery) if an HTML element can contain some text?

For instance, `<br>`, `<hr>` or `<tr>` cannot contain text nodes, while `<div>`, `<td>` or `<span>` can.

The simplest way to test this property is to control the tag names. But is this the best solution? I think it is one of the worst...

EDIT: In order to clarify the sense of the question, need to point out that the perfect answer should consider two problems:

1. According to HTML standards, can the element contain a text node?
2. If the element contains some text, will it be shown?

Obviously, there is a sub-answer for each point of the previous list.

Comment: add some text, see if it added, then remove it? ugly but i don't think there's any other way

Comment: Well, the problem is that technically `<tr>` *can* contain text, it just gets rendered above the table.

Comment: Blacklisting tag names may be the only reliable option...

Comment: @jbabey Not that simple. `$('<br>test</br>').text().length;` returns 4.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off just created your own whitelist of 'text-able' tags in an array.

Comment: checking node name is probably the best solution `var node = $('#test')[0].nodeName; node.match(/br|hr|tr/gi);`

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: Yes, and the answer should consider also this problem: a) test if an element can contain text (considering the HTML standards); b) simply test if the text inside the element is displayed (also if the element could not contain nothing).

Comment: walk the dom by Douglas Crockford and some if's and your done

Comment: @lombausch [Not according to the standard that specifies it as a void element.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/hr.html#hr)

Comment: @h2ooooooo sure, but if you really want you can place some text in it thus besides blacklisting you hardly get a reliable method to detect void elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The W3 standard for "void elements"](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements) specifies:

> **Void elements**
>   area, base, br, col, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, menuitem, meta, param, source, track, wbr

And apparently there's some [unofficial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13915718/247893) tags as well.

You can make a black list and use `.prop('tagName')` to get the tag name:

```
(function ($) {
    var cannotContainText = ['AREA', 'BASE', 'BR', 'COL', 'EMBED', 'HR', 'IMG', 'INPUT', 'KEYGEN', 'LINK', 'MENUITEM', 'META', 'PARAM', 'SOURCE', 'TRACK', 'WBR', 'BASEFONT', 'BGSOUND', 'FRAME', 'ISINDEX'];

    $.fn.canContainText = function() {
        var tagName = $(this).prop('tagName').toUpperCase();

        return ($.inArray(tagName, cannotContainText) == -1);
    };
}(jQuery));

$('<br>').canContainText(); //false
$('<div>').canContainText(); //true
```

Here you can also add your own tags to `cannotContainText` (eg. to add `<tr>` which is not officially a void element as it doesn't match the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements) "*A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances. Void elements can have attributes.*").

Comment: It is a very nice answer. But do you know some way (or an official list like the above one) to consider all the "non-void" elements that should not contain text?

Comment: @VitoShadow I'm not sure but on the [w3 page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html#td) you can see what elements are allowed. If "flow content" is allowed, then it allows text. You might want to crawl w3 for elements without "flow control", but I don't know any other method as of now. [tr, for example, doesn't have flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html#tr).

Comment: Very interesting. Now we only need a method to test if an element can have flow content :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for a list of [void HTML tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html):

> The following is a complete list of the void elements in HTML:
>
> area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

From there you would just test the node to see if it is in the list. For example:

```
var voidNodeTags = ['AREA', 'BASE', ...];
var isNodeVoid = function (node) {
    return voidNodeTags.indexOf(node.nodeName) !== -1;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uQjH/

Comment: Very simple, clean and working solution. But I also need a solution that also consider all the "non-void" elements that should not contain text. Do you some ideas?

Comment: @VitoShadow if there are more elements you want to blacklist, add their tags to the array.

Comment: Do note that `indexOf` on arrays was first added in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with everybody that a blacklist would be a very orthodox way of doing it but if we are really required to test for the ability, then this would be one way I think (with some **jquery**):

```
isTextContainerTag=function(tagName){
    try{       
        var test = $('<'+tagName+'></'+tagName+'>');
        test.html(123);
        if(test.html()=='123'){
            return true;   
        }else{
            return false;   
        }
    }
    catch(err){return false;}
}
```

I tested it on Chrome on various tags names and got these results:

```
    console.log('input',isTextContainerTag('input'));//answer:false
    console.log('textarea',isTextContainerTag('textarea'));//true
    console.log('option',isTextContainerTag('option'));//true
    console.log('ul',isTextContainerTag('ul'));//true
    console.log('li',isTextContainerTag('li'));//true
    console.log('tr',isTextContainerTag('tr'));//true
    console.log('td',isTextContainerTag('td'));//true
    console.log('hr',isTextContainerTag('hr'));//false
    console.log('br',isTextContainerTag('br'));//false
    console.log('div',isTextContainerTag('div'));//true
    console.log('p',isTextContainerTag('p'));//true
    console.log('html',isTextContainerTag('html'));//false
    console.log('body',isTextContainerTag('body'));//false
    console.log('table',isTextContainerTag('table'));//false
    console.log('tbody',isTextContainerTag('tbody'));//true
```

We may also test some real tags using jquery "prop" on these two examples:

```
<div id="A">AAAAAA</div>
<br id="B">
```

Which gives:

```
var obj1 = $('#A').prop('tagName');
var obj2 = $('#B').prop('tagName');
console.log('id:A (div)',isTextContainerTag(obj1));//true
console.log('id:B (br)',isTextContainerTag(obj2));//false
```

I'm sure it is way away from perfect though, but it was fun to look into.

Comment: I tested your solution in Firefox 24, and it doesn't work... It always returns `true`. I think the problem is that `$('<'+tagName+'></'+tagName+'>')` doesn't create a rendered node... Is it possible?

Comment: According to the standards `tr` and `tbody` can't contain text either, so while this *should* give a more accurate representation than a blacklist, it still seems to fail specific times.