# Check if an HTML tag can contain text

Tags: javascript, html, text, tags, element

i'm finding a way to check if an HTML tag is empty (contains no text). first of all, i'm thinking about checking if the tag **can** contain text (which has closing tag).

it turns out:

`<img>`, `<img/>`, `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<input>` would return `false`

`<div></div>`, `<p></p>` would return `true`

please help,
thanks in advance.

Comment: You should investigate the innerText property of an element. It will return an empty string if there is no human readable text, that sounds kind of like what you need correct?

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder sorry for unclear question. actually I want to find out empty elements to remove it and I don't want to remove `img`, `input` (which also have no innerText).

Comment: What constitutes an empty element then? I suppose you could create a list of all the elements that you don't want to filter out, grab all the elements from the page, and then filter out only the elements that are not included in your list of 'empty' elements that you don't want to remove. Each element has a tagName property, where it returns the tag name as an uppercase string. Does that help at all? I have a pretty good idea of the code that would pull this off, but I think you may be able to figure it out if I'm correct in my reasoning above.

Answer (score 2):

The W3 specifies some standard void elements as below link. It may give you some help.

[Test if an element can contain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790442/test-if-an-element-can-contain-text)

Answer (score -3):

```
console.log(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML)
```

You can get html content inside element

Comment: thank you but my purpose is to check if a tag **can** contain text. with your code an empty `div` and an `img` would return the same.